# MySql search using PHP based on multiple variable fields

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I am trying to search in MySql db based on user input something like below. 

User may/not select from the below fields

```
<select name="field_one" id="f1">
<option value="AA">AA</option> 
<option value="BB">BB</option>
<option value="CC">CC</option>
</select>
```

```
<select name="field_two" id="f2">
<option value="11">11</option> 
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
</select>
```

if User selects only 'field_one', then mysql_query should filter only based on 'field_one'. In this case there can be four combination

1. Filed_one is slected and filed_two is not selected
2. Field_One is not selected and field_two is selected
3. Filed_one is not selected and Filed_two is not selected
4. Field_one is selected and Field_Two is selected

What is the best and efficient methode to make this search?

I tried with '`case .... break;`' and '`if`', but when the first condition is met, code stops and does not check the next conditions 
Can any one give me a clue? 
 Thanks in advance for the help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

```
$query = "select * from table_name where 1 ";
            if(!empty($_POST['field1']) ) {
             $query .= " AND field1 like '".trim($_POST['field1'])."'";
            }
            if(!empty($_POST['field2'])) {
             $query .= " AND field2 like '".trim($_POST['field2'])."'";
            }
            // and so on
            $result = mysql_query($query);
```

please use escape string also http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 1):

```
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1";

            if(isset($_POST)){
                if(isset($_POST['field_one'])){
                    $sql.= 'AND  field_one'= $_POST['field_one'];
                }
                if(isset($_POST['field_two'])){
                    $sql.= 'AND field_two'= $_POST['field_two'];
                }
            }

            mysql_query($sql);
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example, not tested and needs lots of variable processing against SQL injection

```
$where = "";
$bits = array();
$bitset=false;

if(isset($_POST['field_one') && strlen($_POST['field_one')) > 0)
  {
  $bitset = true;
  $bits[] = " field1 = $_POST['field_one')"
  }

if(isset($_POST['field_two') && strlen($_POST['field_two')) > 0)
  {
  $bitset = true;
  $bits[] = " field2 = $_POST['field_two')"
  }

if($bitset)
  {
  $where = implode(", " $bits);
  }

$sql = "select * from table " . $where;
```

Comment: I have skipped that and chances are that other will skip that as well. Furthermore, your code has at least 7 syntax errors and will generate an invalid query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PDO & param binding to avoid SQL Injection : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php